# why am i getting None for the player.bet

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class inputs:
    def bet(self):
        """
        takes in the bet from the user and stores it in the player class
        :return: output
        """
        self.bet = input("Enter the amount for your bet : ")
        output = self.bet
        if self.bet.isnumeric() == False:
            print("Use your monke brains and enter correct input")
            inputs.bet(self)
        else:
            return output
    def Aval(self):
        """
        Takes the value for ace and stores it in the player class
        :return: output
        """
        self.aval = input("Enter the value for ACE (1 or 10) : ")
        output = self.aval
        if self.aval.isnumeric() == False:
            print("Use your monke brains and enter correct input")
            inputs.Aval(self)
        elif self.aval.isnumeric() == True:
            if self.aval in ["1", "10"]:
                return output
            else:
                print("I understand you suffer braincell deficiency but I need you to fire up those 2 braincells you have and enter the proper number")
                inputs.Aval(self)
class Player:
    deck = ["A♣", "2♣", "3♣", "4♣", "5♣", "6♣", "7♣", "8♣", "9♣", "10♣", "J♣", "K♣", "Q♣", "A♦", "2♦", "3♦", "4♦", "5♦",
            "6♦", "7♦", "8♦", "9♦", "10♦", "J♦", "K♦", "Q♦", "A♥", "2♥", "3♥", "4♥", "5♥", "6♥", "7♥", "8♥", "9♥",
            "10♥", "J♥", "K♥", "Q♥", "A♠", "2♠", "3♠", "4♠", "5♠", "6♠", "7♠", "8♠", "9♠", "10♠", "J♠", "K♠", "Q♠"]

    total = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = input("Enter your name : ")
        self.bet = inputs.bet(self)
        self.Aval = inputs.Aval(self)

p = Player()
print(p.bet)
print(p.aval)
```

why do i get None for p.bet if the function inputs.bet() runs like 2 - 3 times if you enter wrong input

Comment: When the input is wrong, the call to `inputs.bet(self)` is not returned. Try to change it to `return inputs.bet(self)`

Comment: I dont think it would work , instead it would call the whole bet() function again instead of returning the betting amount

Comment: It's a recursive call so it should return whatever the succeeding `bet()` functions eventually return. Can you have a try?

Comment: Tried it just now on my end. It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `bet`, you need to return the eventual successful input when the user needs to try again.

```
        if self.bet.isnumeric() == False:
            print("Use your monke brains and enter correct input")
            return inputs.bet(self)
         #  ^^^ add this
```

Comment: Have a read about [recursion](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/recursion)